# Add zoom animation to zoom function in arcgis javascript api 4.x

Tags: arcgis-js-api

When I use the zoom method on the view as follows:

```
function zoomIn() {
   view.zoom = view.zoom + 1;
}

function zoomOut() {
   view.zoom = view.zoom - 1;
}
```

It is working correctly but it is zooming abruptly from one scale to another.  How can the zoom method be animated (As how it works when using the +/- zoom control on the map)?

I am using ArcGIS Javascript SDK 4.x

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to zoom with animation.  You actually set a variable with the desired zoom level first and then you call the goTo function of the view and center the map using view.center.  This works correctly with the same animation as the +/- zoom control on the map.

```
function zoomIn() {

    let zm = view.zoom + 1;

    view.goTo({
    target: view.center,
        zoom: zm
    });
}

function zoomOut() {

    let zm = view.zoom - 1;

    view.goTo({
      target: view.center,
      zoom: zm
    });
}
```